# How to make php curl responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design

I use the curl function to pull an external html file into a php page as below. Is there a way to change this to make the file being pulled in responsive to shrink and grow if viewed on a mobile device so that the whole thing is visible in the width. At the moment it cuts off each row and goes over to the next line.

```
<pre> <span class="inner-pre" style="font-size: 11px font-family:sans-serif"><?php

function curl_download($Url){

if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
die('cURL is not installed. Install and try again.');
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$start = strpos($output, '<pre>');
$end = strpos($output, '</pre>', $start);
$length = $end-$start;
$output = substr($output, $start, $length);    


curl_close($ch);

return $output;
}

$str = curl_download('http://www.atletiek.co.za/atletiek.co.za/uitslae/2016BolandJuniors/160226P227.htm');
$re = "/([^\n\r]+)/m"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

$matches = $matches[1];
$str = "";
for($i = 5; $i <= 50; $i++) {
$str .= $matches[$i] . "<br>"; // Preserve the new line
}
echo $str;

?></pre>
```

Comment: how is it a php question?

Comment: I was wondering if one could make the file being pulled in always display at a 100% witdh with php no matter what the device's width and size is. The file being pulled in is dynamically created a constantly changes

Comment: you will require a responsive `<div>` structure for it. It all depends on how do you want to display it.